# What is the role of CSS coding in Accessibility?

Tags: css, accessibility

What is the role of CSS styles in Accessibility? other than to keep presentation and content separate.

How and what we write in CSS file can affect accessibility of site?

Comment: +1: For good question, as most developers don't pay attention to this and people with accessibility problems are ignored :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must see: **[CSS for Accessibility :)](http://24ways.org/2007/css-for-accessibility)** and do help people with accessibility problems. It is our responsibility.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: Yes, it is a must read, we have to take care of those disabled people as well :)

Comment: @sarfaraz - yes some snippets i think i can include in my reset css

Answer (score 1):

Color blindness should be taken into consideration when making CSS styles.

Make high contrast websites rather than "soft" transitions.

Take a look at this article for a thorough explanation: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/contrast-is-king/